# Javascript : Windows 7 taskbar time (Almost Done) But it is still in 24 hour format

Tags: java, javascript, function, datetime, time

I have already created windows 7 time, which is almost done but it is still in 24 hour format.

**JAVASCRIPT :-**

```
<script>
function date_time(id){
    date = new Date;
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth();
    months = new Array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12');
    d = date.getDate();
    day = date.getDay();
    days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    h = date.getHours();
    if(h<10)
    {
            h = ""+h;
    }
    m = date.getMinutes();
    if(m<10)
    {
            m = "0"+m;
    }
a = date.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
    result = ''+h+':'+m+' '+a+'<br/>'+months[month]+'/'+d+'/'+year;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
    setTimeout('date_time("'+id+'");','1');
    return true;
}
</script>
```

**HTML :-**

```
                <span class="right" id="date_time"></span>
            <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = date_time('date_time');</script>
```

**I want just change the format of hour into 12 not 24**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not converting hours to the 12 hours format.

Add the line

```
h = h % 12
```

after the line where you set 'a'.

And remove

```
if(h<10)
{
     h = ""+h;
}
```

Comment: You must remove the 4 lines because it will not work if the hours are lower 10. Before your line   "a = date.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';"  you insert the line which I suggested to add. If the rest of your code works, it should be fine.